# Managing Scroll with touch events in SmartWatch 2

Tags: scroll, touch, sony, sony-smartwatch

I have this:

```
 @Override
 public void onTouch(final ControlTouchEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();

    if (action == Control.Intents.TOUCH_ACTION_PRESS) {
        Log.d("Touch Test", "Touch: Press at " + event.getX() + " - " + event.getY());

    }
    else if (action == Control.Intents.TOUCH_ACTION_RELEASE) {
        Log.d("Touch Test", "Touch: Release at " + event.getX() + " - " + event.getY());            
    } 

}
```

Basically, its working but for single presses.  Let me explain.

If you press the screen and release on same position, lest call it a "click" both logs get fired, the Press first, then the release.

But I want to manage scrolling, so, if I press, then move my finger, and release in other place of the screen, I only get the press event fired.

I want to know start position when pressed and end position when released, so I can scroll the layout!

How can I achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> But I want to manage scrolling, so, if I press, then move my finger, and release in other place of the screen, I only get the press event fired.

I think that's because you are doing a swipe event, so on release it will trigger the `Control.Intents.SWIPE_DIRECTION_[UP|DOWN|RIGHT|LEFT]` action and **not** the Control.Intent.TOUCH_ACTION_RELEASE.

If you don't need the swipe events you can remove the Swipe intent from the manifest. Otherwise you should consider to use the SWIPE intents to manage the scrolling. The main difference is that with Swipe events you don't get the magnitude of the swipe you only get the direction, but that should be enough for the most cases.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think I may be able to do something working with both touch and swipe togheter. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The SmartWatch 2 is not functioning consistently in regard to the touch detection. Thus, not every `TOUCH_ACTION_PRESS` event is followed by a `TOUCH_ACTION_RELEASE` event (as it is the case for the SmartWatch 1), but it can be followed by a `SWIPE` event, for example. Also, the `SWIPE` events are too easily triggered, so any attempt to implement the scrolling as you want it, would not be successful.

Best thing to do is to use the Gallery and ListView for smooth scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

As the others said, the "scroll" as is, is not supported.

The SDK is good, but lacks some functions. I hope Sony update it in the future, however, **it may be too late now**.

This is what I ended doing on my app:

I used a `TOUCH_ACTION_PRESS` to save the press action in a global object, then, I used the `SWIPE` event to get a direction.

In the Swipe routine, I ask if the `PRESS` event has been made, and if so, I do the "scrolling" with the SWIPE direction.

To get a better feel, I ask where the `PRESS` started on the Y axis, so, if lets say the pressed started at bottom of the screen, and the swipe was swipe up, I move the view more than if the press started at half screen.

It is not very smooth, but, I think there is no better way to do it. The other option is to use on screen buttons, but I do not like them.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't fully understood this yet but I am getting three sets of events when I have not got any clickable objects:

1. For simple taps: *onTouch(PRESS)* followed by *onTouch(RELEASE)*
2. For swipes: *onTouch(PRESS)* followed by *onSwipe()*
3. Unfortunately for very short swipes, or slipped taps:
   *onTouch(PRESS)* only

It appears to differ if you have clickable objects. This is the pattern I get when I do:

1. For simple taps: *onTouch(PRESS)* followed by *onTouch(RELEASE)* then *onObjectClick*
2. For all swipes: *onTouch(PRESS)* followed by *onSwipe()*

Since onSwipe only gives the direction and not the event (with location), I cannot find a satisfactory way of handling this except to process all events when I get on onTouch(PRESS) and then undo the tap operation if there is a follow up onSwipe. Depending on what you are doing this undo could be easy or really tricky - but if fast enough the user will never notice...

Turning off swipe in the manifest doesn't help - you just lose the onSwipe events and sadly don't gain the onTouch(RELEASE).